# Constaints in Rotation matrix

Tags: classical-mechanics

In Rigid body rotation, we need only 3 parameters to make a body rotate in any orientation. So to define a rotation matrix in 3d space we only need 3 parameters and we must have 6 constraint equation (6+3=9 no of elements in rotation matrix)

My doubt is if orthogonality conditions R.Transpose(R)=I must be satisfied for rotation matrix (no of constraints=6) and the determinant should be equal to +1 which makes it total 7 constraints, shouldn't be there only two parameters left( instead of 3)

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/575037/2451

Comment: Hi physicshub. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.